# Bisection method for many different types of functions not converging when the search range includes/is nearby a local minimum

Tags: maxima-minima, matlab, bisection

I've been teaching a couple of lessons in computer-aided engineering at university, and part of the lessons have involved using recursive algorithms to find roots such as the **Bisection method**, Newton-Raphson method, and Secant method. My question is specifically regarding the [Bisection method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bisection_method).

I've noticed that when I use the following algorithm in an attempt to find the roots of functions when the following conditions are met, the method does not converge and behaves *strangely*. I will explain after the presenting the algorithm here.

```
for i=1:length(a)
    k = 1;  % start the iterations out at 1 at the beginning of each new search
    while errorCalc>errorTol % while the error calculated remains larger than the tolerance
        c = (a + b)/2;    % calculate the midpoint

        fc = f(r);  % evaluate the function at the midpoint, f is the anonymous function representing the equation to find the root
        
        errorCalc = abs(fc);  % since the error is compared to zero I will use the absolute value

        if fc<0
            a = c;   % replace the lower bound with the midpoint
        elseif fc>0
            b = c;   % replace the upper bound with the midpoint
        end
        k = k+1;
    end
end
```

When the equation `f` has a 1) derivative equal to zero within the original search range, 2) the local extrema is just outside but close to the boundaries of the search range, or 3) derivative of `f` becomes negative anywhere within the search range this algorithm fails to find any root.

In fact, it always converges to the location of the minimum or whichever boundary value is closest to the minimum. When I modify the equations so that there is a maximum just outside the domain instead it is able to find the root without any problems.

I have tried this with polynomials such as $0.8x^4-2.48x^3-1.992x^2+11.3792x-8.79472$ as well as other combinations of transcendental functions without much success. I've only been successful after changing any equation I select to not fit these criteria.

I'm not very experienced with this so it is possible there is some nuance I am missing in my algorithm, or maybe it's an inability built-in to the bisection method. This is my first year teaching too so that isn't helping much.

Comment: Bisection method will work and converge only if the original range $[a,b]$ it is started with has the values of the function of opposite signs at its ends, i.e. $f(a) f(b) \lt 0 $.  Other than that it does not work.

Comment: I see, I guess I had missed that part of the requirements. But that still does not explain why the algorithm is failing when there is a minimum within the range. It finds the minimum instead of the root.

Comment: The conditions for the Bisection method are that $f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$, and that $f(a)$ and $f(b)$ are of opposite sign. This guarantees that there is some root between them. When you take the midpoint $c$, you replace $a$ with $c$ when $f(a)$ and $f(c)$ have the same sign, otherwise you replace $b$ with $c$ (since both have the opposite sign as $a$, this means that $f(b)$ and $f(c)$ must have the same sign). In either case, the new $f(a)$ and $f(b)$ still have opposite sign, so there is still a root between them.

Comment: But your version sets $a = c$ when $f(c) < 0$. If $f(a) > 0 > f(b)$ at the start, this leaves the new $f(a)$ and $f(b)$ with the same sign. You threw out the side of $c$ that had the root, and choose a side that might not have any root. The values of the end points always converges to a single point no matter how you choose the sides, but that point is only guaranteed to be a root if you are careful the keep the endpoints at opposite signs. To fix, check before starting that $f(a)f(b) < 0$. If not, give an error. If so, check if $f(a) < 0$. if not, swap $a$ and $b$. then start your search.

Comment: One other point. that outer for loop accomplishes nothing more than wasting some extra time, and making sure $k = 1$ at the end, no matter how many iterations were actually run. I cannot even imagine what the idea behind it would be.

Comment: The outer for loop is for when there are multiple ranges to search within, hence multiple lower bounds a and upper bounds b, therefore the iterations k must be reset when you start a new search. If there is only search being done, then k is never reset.